# Running Room DAO from setOnClickListener within onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a recyclerview that displays a cardview of my sql data. I now want to add actions to each card to be able to delete the data and update the view.

I have added an OnClickListener within my onBindViewHolder in my adapter. The code runs but it doesn't delete the data. If I run the same click action again I get "lateinit property mWorkerHandler has not been initialized". Here is my listener code. I know this is probably not correct but this is my attempt so far:

```
    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener{
        var mDb: TaskDatabase? = null
        mDb = TaskDatabase.getInstance(this.mInflater.context)
        lateinit var mDbWorkerThread: DbWorkerThread
        mDbWorkerThread = DbWorkerThread("dbWorkerThread2")
        mDbWorkerThread.start()
        val task = Runnable { mDb?.taskDao()?.deleteById(holder.id as Int) }
        mDbWorkerThread.postTask(task)
        TaskDatabase.destroyInstance()
        mDbWorkerThread.quit()
    }
```

One piece I am not sure about at all is the context for the database. The second piece I am not sure about is the threading. Maybe there is a better approach all together?

Comment: Why not use swipeToDelete method?

Comment: @ShowYoungSoyinka - I didn't know/think about the swipe method. Thank you. I would like to see this model work first and then I will look at adding swipe. I think it is nice to have an obvious action on the card vs just a swipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you are calling notify datasetchanged on the adapted to let it know to update the list after you have deleted the code. I wouldn't want to put a code like this on recycler view adapter's onbindviewholder() function. Make function in your activity to delete the entry from db, once it is deleted call notifydatasetchanged on the adapter. Don't forget to call this on main thread when you return from a background thread for db.
Make an interface and pass I'd of item to be deleted from the adapter to the activity and write the delete logic there.

**Update:**

You can do it this way:

Declare interface:

```
public interface MyInterface{
   public void foo(int deleteThisId);
}
```

Let your Activity imlement it:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface{

//Somewhere in on create where you init the adapter
    adapter = MyAdapter(this); // where this is the instance for the interface which will be used in adapter

    public void foo(int deleteThisId){
        //do stuff with deleteThisId
        //when finished with delete operation 
        adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    }
```

}

Then pass your activity to MyAdater:

```
public MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<>{
private MyInterface listener;

public MyAdapter(MyInterface listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
}
```

And in onClick listner of onBindViewHolder() in adapter, when you need to call that Activity method:

```
listener.foo(idToBeDeleted);
```

Comment: I have to set my onClickListener in the adapter as far as I know. Because I need the listener for each button on each card. How do I call a function in the activity from the adapter within the listener?

Comment: I have updated the code showing how can you implement the interface. Search more about how to use interfaces if you are stuck somewhere

Comment: This required quite a bit of changes to make it work and I didn't need to notify the adapter because the data is already populated with Observer. However, the basic idea of the implementation of an Interface worked great. I also had to convert it all to kotlin.

Comment: @BrandonBearden I didn't realize that you asked question in Kotlin but yeah the basic idea is same. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

@Brandon Bearden, 
There are two main things to consider here. First, Room database shouldn't be accessed in the main thread. Which means your delete should happen on the background thread. And when the delete is successful, you need to inform the RecyclerView adapter that the dataset was changed [*adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()*] to reflect the changes in the view. This has to happen on the main/UI thread. Please make sure this is handled properly.

Comment: I am trying to run another thread in the listener, I am not sure my syntax is correct or that I am starting and ending the thread correctly for the context. My data for the view is populated using Observer. I am fairly certain it will update when the delete is successful they way it is implemented.